# missing nested template display

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to display the content in my `portfolio.html` file but nothing is showing up.

portfolio section in home.html:

```
<!-- portfolio -->
<section id="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="title">
        Some of our work
      </div>
      <div class="caption">
        Costco sample
      </div>
      {% block portfolio %} {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

portfolio.html:

```
{% extends "home/home.html" %}

    {% block portfolio %}

          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#" class="portfolio-link">
              <div class="portfolio-hover">

              </div>
              <img src="../static/images/roundicons.png">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">

          </div>
        {% endblock %}
```

template format:

```
#####index.html
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

#############



#####home.html

{% extends "index/index.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}

  {% block portfolio %}{% endblock %}

{% endblock %}

#############



#####portfolio.html

{% extends "home/home.html" %}

  {% block portfolio %}
     CONTENT
  {% endblock%}

{% endblock %}

#############
```

Missing content in the inspector:

[image]

Comment: Is your view rendering home.html or portfolio.html?

Comment: @Joseph My view is rendering `home.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your view is rendering `home.html`, then you don't want `portfolio.html` to extend it. Rather, you want `home.html` to include `portfolio.html`. Instead of using `{% block portfolio %}`, use `{% include "portfolio.html" %}`

However, if your view was going to render `portfolio.html`, then it would extend `home.html`.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused because I have `index.html` with a `content block` in it. I use `{% extends index/index.html %}` within `home.html` and this loads my `home.html` page. I tried using the same logic but starting at the `home.html` level and performing this on `portfolio.html`

Comment: MY mistake. I think there are some flaws in my code. I'll try to fix them and try out your suggestion

Comment: I'm not sure how else to explain. When you use `{% extends %}`, your view must render that template. So if your `portfolio.html` is a template that extends another template, you want to render `portfolio.html`. However, if you just want the contents of the rendered `portfolio.html` template inside another template, you use `{% include %}` within the template that your view is actually rendering (in your case, `home.html`).

Comment: I hope by selecting an answer you've gotten it working :) If for some reason you haven't, please update your question here with your view code and I can try to continue to help!

Comment: Thanks to your explanation I understand! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to render content from portfolio.html in home.html...try the opposite.

You normally render the child templates

Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/ ...slowly :P. Bassically you create a basic generic template (parent - home.html in your case) that contains some blocks and then extend it and override the blocks on the children (portfolio.html)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by try the opposite. Sorry I am new to Django. I rendered `home.html` and within that file, I am trying to render `portfolio.html` in `home.html` because I wanted to have two files so my code is more modular.